# How to create an Xcode storyboard (for Xamarin.Mac) with multiple unrelated views

Tags: xcode, xamarin, storyboard, xib, xamarin.mac

I am in the process of porting an existing Xamarin.Forms application (currently running on iOS, Android and UWP) to macOS. The app is well-structured, with a view model layer that was designed with this platform transition in mind, so I don't foresee any major problems hooking into the existing codebase. All in need to do is create a UI, using an Xcode storyboard, that is functionally equivalent to the existing Xamarin.Forms UI. Simple, huh?

Unfortunately, I am a complete newbie to Xcode (having previously used it only to compile Xamarin.iOS apps) and it seems that most of the good tutorials are oriented toward iOS development.

My goal is quite simple: to build a number of independent views, only one of which will be visible at any given time, according to the state of the application. When a view is made visible, its controller (and the associated view model from the existing codebase) will be instantiated and any existing controller / view model will be disposed.

I have experimented using a `Container View` in the main view controller, loading the context-specific views as required, using `InstantiateControllerWithIdenifier`. Although this almost works, the auto-resizing is broken, with the result that the contained view does not follow the resizing of its containing window. (For comparison, if I use an embed segue to link the container to the contained view, resizing works fine).

So, I have 3 questions:

1. Is this a legitimate way to implement navigation between views? If not, what is the recommended alternative?
2. Is there something I can do to activate auto-resizing in the above scenario?
3. Can I expect any other side-effects from this use of containment and, if so, how can I fix them?

Many thanks,
Tim

Comment: In case you do not know; Xamarin.Forms (2.3.3.166-pre4) now includes support for `Xamarin.Mac` (target:`xamarinmac20`)... Do not know if that is an option for your App design, project deadline, how much alpha/beta pain you can deal with, etc... but it is now an option...

Comment: @SushiHangover. Oh, that's great news! Thanks :) There is already so much pain with Xcode that I am more than happy to give it a try.